# how can i convert a string like 123245wkjsvd :/' to list and sort?

Tags: python, list, string

I want to convert it to a list and sort them alphabetically and then turn the result to a string again. Well i want to do this in python. how can i do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are shorter one-liners, but here it is statement-by-statement:

```
# initial string
input_string = "123245wkjsvd :/'"
# Convert string to list of characters
list_of_chars = list(input_string)
# Sort list
list_of_chars.sort()
# Convert to string
output_string = ''.join(list_of_chars)
```

Shortest one-liner:

```
print ''.join(sorted("123245wkjsvd :/'"))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"".join(sorted(list("123245wkjsvd :/'")))
```

Comment: wow, posted the same time to the second. +1 for doing it in one line.

Comment: You do not need to convert the string to a list. `sorted` takes any iterable as input.

Comment: Why ever do you do `list(...)`? `str` is iterable, pass it straight to `sorted`.

Comment: Maybe OP not only doesn't know the answer but is also vague on the complete question. Sometimes you have to figure our what the question really is.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list('123245wkjsvd :/\'')
l.sort()
''.join(l)
```